# Which pre-trained model do I need to use for long text classification in BERT?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

We know that bert has a max length limit of tokens = 512, So if an acticle has a length of much bigger than 512, such as 10000 tokens in text. In this case, How can I use BERT?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1. Truncate sequences longer than 512 tokes.
2. You can use a [sliding window](https://finetune.indico.io/chunk.html) like approach as implemented by the `chunk_long_sequences` feature in finetune transformers library.

In your case, with sequences of around 10000 tokens, I'd go with option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, there are better transformer-based (i.e., BERT-like) solutions for long documents than sliding windows. Models like [Longformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.05150) and [BigBird](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.14062) exist specifically for this purpose, and their implementation supports up to 4096 tokens:

> ... we propose, BigBird, a sparse attention mechanism that reduces this quadratic dependency to linear ... **The proposed sparse attention can handle sequences of length up to 8x of what was previously possible using similar hardware**. As a consequence of the capability to handle longer context, BigBird drastically improves performance on various NLP tasks such as question answering and summarization ...
>
> (Taken from BigBird paper)

Code for BigBird and Longformer is publically available on GitHub ([google-research/bigbird](https://github.com/google-research/bigbird) and [allenai/longformer](https://github.com/allenai/longformer)). Implementations also exist on Huggingface.